# Getting past month once month is finished

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i have two categories tab, up coming events and past events, let says i have events for up coming 3 month once these month past i want these events to be display as past events in past month tabs, lets say 1st month is may, 2nd month is june and 3rd month is july so if this month is june then i want may to be displayed as past event tab so on if this month is july then i want to display both may and june in past event tabs

https://i.ibb.co/C5195NM/1er.jpg

i have achieved  up coming events by using ACF Reapter with Date field for date, text field for title, image field for image and textarea for event content, as mention above i want this up coming events to be display in past event gradually once month ends

```
<?php if( have_rows('up_coming_events_listing') ): ?>
                <div class="match-schedule-date">
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                              <?php 
                                  $row = 1;
                                  while( have_rows('up_coming_events_listing') ): the_row();
                                  $title = get_sub_field('tab_date');
                                  $titleId = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $title));
                              ?>

                             <li class="nav-item ">
                              <a class="nav-link <?php if($row == 1) {echo 'active';}?>"
                                href="#<?php echo $titleId; ?>"
                                role="tab"
                                data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $titleId; ?>"
                                >
                                 <?php echo $title; ?>  
                                </a>
                                </li>

                             <?php $row++; endwhile; ?>

                        </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>

        <?php if( have_rows('up_coming_events_listing') ): ?>
                            <div class="tab-content">

                        <?php 
                            $roww = 1;
                            while( have_rows('up_coming_events_listing') ): the_row();
                              $titler = get_sub_field('tab_date');
                              $titleIdr = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $titler));
                        ?>

                                <div class="tab-pane <?php if($roww == 1) {echo 'active';}?>" id="<?php echo $titleIdr; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?php echo $titleIdr; ?>-tab">

                                    <?php if( have_rows('evens_description') ): ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <?php 
                                    $rowing = 1;
                                      while( have_rows('evens_description') ): the_row();
                                      $tider = get_sub_field('event_title');
                                      $titleIdr = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tider));


                                      $date = get_sub_field ('event_date');
                                      $mImage = get_sub_field ('event_image');
                                      $description = get_sub_field('event_details');
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="sam">
                                                <div class="match-image">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $mImage['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $mImage['alt'] ?>" class="img-fluid" />
                                                </div>
                                              <div class="match-content">
                                                <h4><?php echo $tider; ?></h4>
                                                <p><?php echo $date; ?></p>
                                                <p class="tppi"><?php echo $description; ?></p>

                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                    <?php $rowing++; endwhile; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                </div>
                                    <?php $roww++; endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

so now im unable to display up coming events in past events tabs once this month have ends....

Comment: a different approach would be to only fetch the correct datasets out of the database by doing mysql date math. here you can check the docs if interested https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

What type of field is

```
get_sub_field('tab_date')
```

You could set this as a date picker and just set it to the first of the month then in your template code get the tab_date and get the current date and compare the month values.